# preg_replace for closing tags only works for one instance

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have the following stored in a database table...

```
<section id="introduction">
  <h2 id="a1">Introduction</h2>
  <div class="Article collapse in article" id="b1">
    (Some text)
  </div>
</section>

<section id="history">
  <h2 id="a2">History</h2>
  <div class="Article collapse in article" id="b2">
    (Some text)
  </div>
</section>
```

I'd like to insert an element ('XXX') before each div's closing tag...

```
<section id="introduction">
  <h2 id="a1">Introduction</h2>
  <div class="Article collapse in article" id="b1">
    (Some text)
    XXX
  </div>
</section>
```

Of course, I have to make sure my script ignores nested div's. The following script almost works:

```
 $Content = preg_replace('/<div class="Article collapse in article" id="(.*?)">([^`]*?)<\/div>/', '<div class="Article collapse in article" id="$1">$2XXX</div>', $Content);
```

In fact, it does work - but just once; it inserts XXX at the end of the first section only. Also, I discovered that it doesn't ignore nested div's.

Does anyone know how I can fix those problems?

Comment: Yes: DON'T USE REGEX!

Answer (score -1):

Try [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). It will make these things a lot easier for you.

Comment: I actually downloaded simplehtmldom just a couple days ago. It's cool, but some critics don't like it for one reason or other. I'm still trying to sort out the differences between regex, str_replace, preg_replace and DOM parsing (which has spawned so many tools, including simplehtmldom). P.S. I didn't vote your answer down, however; someone else did. The same thing happened on a discussion where someone first introduced me to simplehtmldom.

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom  try this regex `$re = "/<div class=\"Article collapse in article\" id=\"(.*?)\">([^`]*?)<\\/div>/m"; `

Comment: Thank you, but I probably deserved a downvote or three. I admit after reading the answer this question was marked duplicate for, I've learned some things. simplehtmldom has been easy for me to use in the past, but I will be looking into libxml based libraries moving forward.